# Returning to the next instruction following the one stored in Eip register

Tags: assembly, x86

I have written a assembly function that handles an interrupt. I want to return to the instruction following the one that caused the interrupt. Here is my code,

```
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp,%ebp
    pushal
    movl    %esp, %eax
    pushl   %eax
    pushl   $0
    call    divzero

    addl    $8, %esp        /* add 8 to the stack pointer to skip the two variables*/ 
    popal   
    popl    %ebp            /* restore %ebp */
    popl    %eax            /* pop return address from stack and store in eax */
    add     $4, %eax    /* add 4 to value of eax to get the address of next instruction */
    jmp     %eax
```

The platform I am coding on is x86 32 bits. I have written comments from my understanding of how the stack works but I am getting invalid opcode interrupt. Here is the stack trace.

```
exception 6 (invalid opcode) currpid 3 (Main process)
CS EFC0008 eip 1028D4
eflags 10297
register dump:
eax 001028CC (1059020)
ecx 0EFC8FFC (251432956)
edx 00000000 (0)
ebx 00121000 (1183744)
esp 0EFC8FB8 (251432888)
ebp 0EFC8FB8 (251432888)
esi 00000000 (0)
edi 00000000 (0)
```

For reference I am adding my main function here:

```
process main(void)
{
    
        asm("int $0");
        kprintf("hello\n");
        int i = 4 / 0; <- Casue of interrupt
        kprintf("hello again\n"); -< The place I want to return to.

}
```

Comment: You're assuming an instruction is 4 bytes long, but that's completely false in general - x86 has variable length instructions, anywhere from 1 to 10 bytes or more.  You can't tell the address of the next instruction except by decoding the current one, which basically means having a disassembler in your interrupt handler.  In this case at least you can be fairly sure the faulting instruction was `div` or `idiv`, but even those can be 2 or 3 or more bytes with instruction prefixes.  AFAIK your goal isn't really something you can practically do without an awful lot of work.

Comment: It's also unlikely to be a good idea - it'll have the effect of the divide by zero effectively returning garbage, and having your program continue to operate on garbage data is worse than having it die.

Comment: Also, compilers know that divide by zero is undefined behavior, so they can do whatever they want, and they won't necessarily actually generate the divide instruction.  clang for example just deletes it, e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/xe3PaM.

Comment: This code is for operating system that I am writing specifically xinu. @NateEldredge

Comment: @NateEldredge I wouldn't say it's an awful amount of work, but it's gonna be around 10 kB of code to decode instruction lengths and prefixes correctly.

Answer (score -2):

This did the trick for me:

```
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp,%ebp
    pushal
    movl    %esp, %eax
    pushl   %eax
    pushl   $0
    call    divzero

    addl    $8, %esp        /* add 8 to the stack pointer to skip the two variables*/ 
    popal                   /* resotre the flags */
    addl    $4, 4(%ebp)     /* add 4 to the return address */
    popl    %ebp            /* restore %ebp */
    iret                    /* return from the function */
```

Comment: How do you know the `div` instruction is 4 bytes long?  What if it's `div dword [table + ebx*4]` or something, with opcode + modrm + SIB + disp32 = 7 bytes?  You probably have a compiler-generated instruction of `idiv dword [ebp + disp8]` or something, although that's only 3 bytes.  So maybe `idiv dword [esp + disp8]` which is 4 bytes.