# Change the return address AT&T Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a assembly function below. Due to what I'm trying to do, this function returns to code in C but it is the line of code that calls my assembly function, resulting in an infinite loop. Here is my function:

```
disableDivideZero:
        pushl %ebp 
        movl %esp, %ebp 
        call dividebyzero
        movl %ebp, %esp 
        popl %ebp 
        ret
```

How would I change the return address so it skips the instruction that it is currently returning to??

I've tried addl $4, 4(%ebp) right before my function returns.

Apologies in advance, I'm new to assembly. I'm on x86 32 bit

Comment: Why have you deleted the code?  Without it, your question is not comprehensible, and can't really be answered except by saying "this is not supposed to happen so you have messed up somewhere"/

Answer (score 2):

Right before your function returns you've *popped* the `ebp` which is the frame pointer for the *previous function*. You need to place the add *before* the `popl %ebp` so that  `ebp` is still pointing to this frame.

Also, is 4 the correct offset to add to the return address - x86 instructions are of variable length, so you need to know the length of the instruction you're jumping back to - and decoding the instruction lengths in x86 isn't an easy one.

Comment: Do you know how I could do that? The instruction it is jumping back to is:
int x = 10/0;

Comment: That is not an (machine code) instruction, that is a *C language statement*. Actually it is a C language declaration with initialization. In general it is impossible to jump over statements in optimized code, they're interleaved all over.

Comment: What if I do in line assembly asm("int $0"), would that still be impossible to get the length?

Comment: What it means is that it is hard to get the length of the instruction in general. Of course you can use a disassembler and see what instruction was generated for `10 / 0` and add *that* offset, and perhaps you should also make sure that the target registers *ax/*dx would hold a sensible value.

Comment: INT $0 is always 2 bytes. If you’re just doing an experiment, you can use that. But if you’re trying to build an actual application that does something useful you need to be more robust than that.

Comment: In my opinion, a better approach would be to use something like setjmp/longjmp, where the caller provides a location in the code to resume after the fault and receives an indication of the error, rather than just skipping the faulting instruction with no indication.

Comment: @prl: `int $0` is 2 bytes, but you have no guarantee about what the compiler put after the `call` instruction, before asm for the next C statement.  With no args to pop, it's somewhat likely that it's `call xyz` ; `int $0`.  But the entire idea here seems totally misguided, as you say.

Comment: @D.programa: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64037899/returning-to-the-next-instruction-following-the-one-stored-in-eip-register which is someone working on a very similar problem, maybe one of your classmates.  This elaborates on why there is no really good way to do what you intend.